# Robot Framework Package Initialization

Tags: python, automation, initialization, robotframework

I'm working on a Robot Framework package, and I've encountered an issue with its initialization and usage.

I've developed a Robot Framework package named ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage that is intended to be used for API testing. The package contains custom keywords, including one named SendGETRequest, which is used to send GET requests.

Project structure:

```
ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage/ 
├── __init__.py 
└── Resources/
     └── robot_resources/
          └── custom_keywords.robot
```

The keywords should be exposed from the init file. The package will eventually be uploaded in the Azure DevOps artifact and installed into different test projects via pip install. But now the keywords "SendGETRequest" are not accessible in **init**.py file.

Here's a summarized version of the code in the **init**.py file:

```
import sys
from robot.api import TestSuite
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
sys.path.append('/Users/samuelcheng/Documents/Atlantis-Robotframework-Package/ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage/')



class ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage:
    def __init__(self, portal=None, useFiddlerProxies=False, *otherSettings):
        """
        This is the initialization of this package.
        The moment you import the package, it is run.
        Its aim is to configure some settings based on the portal that is used.

        Input:
        - Portal:               This is the name of the portal in which the application runs.
                                The current options are under the variable portalOptions.
                                If testers want to use this package in other portals, the settings should be added to this function.
                                The default value is None
        - useFiddlerProxies:    This determines whether the Fiddler proxies are used.
                                Fiddler is very helpful when setting up API tests, but since it is not available (currently) in Azure,
                                the proxies should not be used when run in the pipeline.
        - otherSettings:        This is where leftover configuration settings can be given.
                                For example, __FiscaalNummer & __SelectedWerkgeverNaam for test.
        """
        global proxies
        global url
        global cookiesTemplate
        global headersTemplate
        global endpointPreflight

        portalOptions = ["test", "test", "KCC Inkijk"]
        if useFiddlerProxies:
            proxies = {'http': "127.0.0.1:8888", 'https': "127.0.0.1:8888"}
        else:
            proxies = None
        if portal in portalOptions:
            if portal == 'Werknemersportaal':
                url = "https://test-netcore.otod.t-dc.ba.test.nl"
                cookiesTemplate = {'(.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.[a-zA-Z0-9=_-]*)': None, 'EWSESSION-T': None,
                                   'EWSESSION-T_S': None, 'XSRF-TOKEN': None}
                headersTemplate = {'XSRF-TOKEN': None, 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': None,
                                   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
                endpointPreflight = "/kias/mijnbezwaar/api/bezwaarschriften/getcurrentbezwaarschrift"
                # TODO: test url
                # TODO: logout
            elif portal == 'test':
                url = "https://test.otod.t-dc.ba.test.nl"
                cookiesTemplate = {'ASP.NET_SessionId': None, 'WerkgeverSamlAuthT': None, 'WerkgeverSamlAuthT1': None,
                                   '__FiscaalNummer': otherSettings[0], '__SelectedWerkgeverNaam': otherSettings[1]}
                endpointPreflight = "/bezwaarenberoep/api/bezwaar/getbezwaarschriften"
            elif portal == "KCC Inkijk":
                url = "https://test-netcore.otod.t-dc.ba.test.nl"
                cookiesTemplate = {'(.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.[a-zA-Z0-9=_-]*)': None, 'KCCINKIJK': None,
                                   'XSRF-TOKEN': None}
                headersTemplate = {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': None, 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
            else:
                BuiltIn().log_to_console(
                    str(portal) + " is not a valid portal for this package. \nCurrently the available portals are: " + str(
                        portalOptions))

            self._requests_library = None
            #   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # # Load the custom_keywords.robot file as a test suite
            # self.suite = TestSuite()
            # self.suite.resource.imports.resource = 'custom_keywords.robot'

            # # Expose the custom keywords in the package
            # self.SendGETRequest = self.suite.resource.keywords["SendGETRequest"]

            # # This allows users to import and use the custom keywords directly from the package name
            # __all__ = [
            #     "ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage",  # Class name
            #     "SendGETRequest"
            # ]
            #   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            # #   import custom keywords from custom_keywords.robot
            # resource_path = "ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage/custom_keywords.robot"
            # TestSuite().resource.imports.library(resource_path)

            # Load the custom_keywords.robot file as a test suite
            self.suite = TestSuite()

            # Import custom keywords using library syntax
            resource_path = "ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage/Resources/robot_resources/custom_keywords.robot"
            self.suite.resource.imports.library(resource_path)

            # Expose the custom keywords in the package
            self.SendGETRequest = self.suite.resource.keywords["SendGETRequest"]
            BuiltIn().log_to_console("SendGETRequest keyword:", self.SendGETRequest)
            sys.stdout.flush()

            # This allows users to import and use the custom keywords directly from the package name
            __all__ = [
                "ApppRobotFrameworkApiPackage",  # Class name
                "SendGETRequest"
            ]

    def get_requests_library(self):
        """
        Since the Requests Library is a stateful library to ensure one continues to use the same session,
        We have to use 1 instance of the library throughout the code.
        First, it is checked if there already is an instance of the library (which is set to None initially)
        If there isn't an instance yet, it will create and return a new instance.
        Otherwise, it will return the already created instance of the library.
        """
        if self._requests_library is None:
            self._requests_library = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('RequestsLibrary')
        return self._requests_library
```

custom_keywords.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     JSONLibrary
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     Collections

# ... (other settings and imports)

*** Keywords ***
SendGETRequest
    [Arguments]    ${endpoint}    ${headers}
    Create Session    mysession    ${url}    proxies=${proxies}
    ${response}=    Get Request    mysession    ${endpoint}    headers=${headers}    expected_status=anything
    Set Suite Variable    ${response}
    ${status}    ${response_body}=    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Evaluate    json.dumps(${response.json()})
    Run Keyword If    '${status}' == 'FAIL'    Set Variable    ${response_body}    '{}'
    Set Suite Variable    ${response_body}
    [Return]    ${response}
```

The keywork "SendGetRequest" is accessible

Comment: So if i understand, you want to import a resource file from python package ?

Comment: From the docs; https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files

Comment: > Searching resource files from the module search path makes it possible to bundle them into Python packages as package data and importing them like package/example.resource.